# Are function pointers evil?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have been told by more senior, experienced and better-educated programmers than myself that the use of [function-pointers](/questions/tagged/function-pointers) in [c](/questions/tagged/c) should be avoided.  I have seen the fact that some code contains function pointers as a rationale not to re-use that code, even when the only alternative is complete re-implementation.  Upon further discussion I haven't been able to determine why this would be.  I am happy to use function pointers where appropriate, and like the interesting and powerful things they allow you to do, but am I throwing caution to the wind by using them?

I see the pros and cons of function pointers as follows:

Pros:

1. Great opportunity for code modularity
2. OO-like features in non-OO c (i.e. code and data in the same object)
3. How else could you reasonably implement a callback?

Cons:

1. Negative impact to code readability - not always obvious what function is actually called when a function pointer is invoked
2. Minor performance hit compared to a direct function call

I think Con # 1. can usually reasonably be mitigated by well chosen symbol names and good comments.  And Con # 2. will in general not be a big deal.  Am I missing something - are there other reasons to avoid function pointers like the plague?

*This question looks a little discussion-ey, but I'm looking for good reasons why I shouldn't use function pointers, not opinions*

Comment: Prehaps take a look here? Semi-related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667410/the-benefits-of-using-function-pointers?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you ask these more senior, experienced and better-educated programmers what they mean while you have their attention?

Comment: No, they aren't evil.

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I no longer have their attention - they have found work elsewhere.  So I am asking the more senior, experienced and better-educated programmers on SO - Is that OK?

Comment: Them finding work as far away as possible (preferably in a different field?) sounds like great news.

Comment: Con #2 is generally wrong. On modern systems, **all** calls to functions in shared libraries are **technically** indirect calls (equivalent to function pointers). On modern cpus, there is essentially no cost to indirect calls as long as the target address is predictable by the cpu, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: You made up the question

Comment: I dont see any reasonable "con". Con1 is not really a feature function pointers but anything can be obfuscated. Con2: If you actually can avoid this performance hit, then simply dont use a function pointer. Thats still no reason to call them evil... apples arent evil just because they dont taste like bananas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointers are not evil. The main times you "shouldn't" use them are when either:

1. The use is gratuitous, i.e. not actually needed for what you're doing, or
2. In situations where you're writing hardened code and the function pointer might be stored at a location you're concerned may be a likely candidate for buffer overflow attacks.

As for when function pointers are needed, Adam's answer provided some good examples. The common theme in all those examples is that the caller needs to be able to provide part of the code that runs from the called function. Without function pointers, the only way you could do this would be to copy-and-paste the implementation of the function and change part of it to call a different function, for every individual usage case. For `qsort` and `bsearch`, which can be implemented portably, this would just be a nuisance and hideously ugly. For thread creation, on the other hand, without function pointers you would have to copy and paste part of *the system implementation* for the particular OS you're running on, and adapt it to call the function you want called. This is obviously unacceptable; your program would then be completely non-portable.

As such, function pointers are absolutely necessary for some tasks, and for other tasks, they are a major convenience which allows general code to be reused. I see no reason why they should not be used in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not evil.  They're absolute necessary in order to implement various features such as callback functions in C.

Without function pointers, you could not implement:

- [`qsort(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)
- [`bsearch(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch)
- [Window procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Threads](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)
- [Signal handlers](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)

And many more.

Comment: This answer has good examples and I +1'd it, but it doesn't really express the class of problems the examples are all special cases of.